# c++ variadic template constructor initialization list of members and mixins

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, variadic-templates

I am trying to initialize a variable number of mixins (`ThresholdSensor<>` , `TrendSensor`, `EdgeSensor`) from my host class (`BaseSensor`) that also happen to require as constructor argument, a member of the host class (`BaseSensor::bsd`). I fail in both tasks miserably :)

I am using c++11 , gcc 4.7.1 (so no "emplace" for the std::map) and the code is the following:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout std::endl
#include <string>   // std::string
#include <map>   // std::map

using namespace std;

struct BaseSensorData
{
    BaseSensorData(const string & _sensorName)
        : sensorName(_sensorName)
    {}

    const string sensorName;
};

class TrendSensor //mixin for BaseSensor
{
    public:
        TrendSensor( BaseSensorData & bsd , size_t _windowSize , const double & _trainRangefactor)
        {
            cout << "TrendSensor: " << _windowSize << " " << bsd.sensorName << " " << _trainRangefactor << endl;
        }
};

typedef struct{ double trough; double peak; } Edges;
class EdgeSensor  //mixin for BaseSensor
{
    public:
        EdgeSensor( BaseSensorData & bsd , size_t _windowSize , const double _rangeFactor)
        {
            cout << "EdgeSensor: " << _windowSize << " " << bsd.sensorName << " " << _rangeFactor << endl;
        }
};

class CO2Threshold //mixin for ThresholdSensor
{
    std::map<std::string , double>thresholds;

    public:
        CO2Threshold( const double & _toxicThres , const double & _zeroThres , const double & )
        {
            thresholds["toxic"] = _toxicThres;
            thresholds["zero"] = _zeroThres;
            cout << "CO2Threshold: " << _toxicThres << " " << thresholds["zero"] << endl;
        }
};
class O2Threshold //mixin for ThresholdSensor
{
    std::map<std::string , double>thresholds;

    public:
        O2Threshold( const double & _toxicThres , const double & _lowThres , const double & _elecChemThres )
        {
            thresholds["toxic"] = _toxicThres;
            thresholds["low"] = _lowThres;
            thresholds["elecchem"] = _elecChemThres;
            cout << "O2Threshold: " << _toxicThres << " " << thresholds["low"] << " " << thresholds["elecchem"] << endl;
        }
};

template<typename ThresholdMixin> //CO2Threshold , O2Threshold , or others ...
class ThresholdSensor : public ThresholdMixin  //mixin for BaseSensor
{
    public:
        ThresholdSensor ( BaseSensorData & bsd
                        , const size_t & _windowSize
                        , const double & _toxicThres)
            : ThresholdMixin
                ( _toxicThres //3x the same arg
                , _toxicThres //just for the sake
                , _toxicThres //of this exercise
                )
        {
            cout << "ThresholdSensor: " << _windowSize << " " << bsd.sensorName << " " << endl;
        }

};

template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public SensorType ... //to my BaseSensor class
{
    BaseSensorData bsd;

    public:
        BaseSensor(const string& _sensorName , size_t _windowSize , const double d)
            :
            bsd(_sensorName) //this causes "Wreorder" warning. 
            ,
            SensorType( bsd , _windowSize , d )...
        {
            cout << "BaseSensor: " << _windowSize << " " << bsd.sensorName << " " << endl;
        }

};

int main() {
    BaseSensor<ThresholdSensor<CO2Threshold> , TrendSensor, EdgeSensor> bs{string("test"),60U , 14.5f};
    //BaseSensor<EdgeSensor> bs2;
}
```

Focusing on `BaseSensor` , I run the executable with `gdb` and I realised that there is no way to get the "bsd" member to initialise first. The "SensorType" mixins will be init first. So how can I init the bsd first?

Secondly, going through the execution step by step, I realised that execution steps only into "ThresholdSensor" and never in "TrendSensor" or "EdgeSensor". Why is that? I though all mixins would be evaluated with the ellipsis syntax. Would `initializer_list` help with the init ordering somehow? Would `initializer_list` still be the proposed solution if I included the info that ultimately the BaseSensor mixins will have a different number (and type) of arguments and that each mixin will require different values for these arguments.. ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like very much the following solution but...

First: you can modify the `SensorType` classes to receiving (as first argument of the constructor) a **pointer** to `BaseSensorData` instead of a reference; by example, `TendSensor` become

```
class TrendSensor //mixin for BaseSensor
 {
   public:
      TrendSensor (BaseSensorData * pBsd, size_t _windowSize,
                   const double & _trainRangefactor)
       { std::cout << "TrendSensor: " << _windowSize << " "
            << pBsd->sensorName << " " << _trainRangefactor << std::endl; }
 };
```

Second: you can modify `BaseSensor` deriving it from `BaseSensorData` (important: before the `SensorType...` pack) and deleting the `bsd` member; `BaseSensor` become

```
template <typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public BaseSensorData, public SensorType ...
 {
   public:

      BaseSensor (const std::string & _sensorName, size_t _windowSize,
                  const double d)
         : BaseSensorData(_sensorName), SensorType(this, _windowSize, d )...
            { std::cout << "BaseSensor: " << _windowSize << " "
              << sensorName << " " << std::endl; } 
 };
```

The full example follows

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout std::endl
#include <string>   // std::string
#include <map>      // std::map

struct BaseSensorData
 {
   BaseSensorData (const std::string & _sensorName)
      : sensorName(_sensorName)
    {}

   const std::string sensorName;
 };

class TrendSensor //mixin for BaseSensor
 {
   public:
      TrendSensor (BaseSensorData * pBsd, size_t _windowSize,
                   const double & _trainRangefactor)
       { std::cout << "TrendSensor: " << _windowSize << " "
            << pBsd->sensorName << " " << _trainRangefactor << std::endl; }
 };

typedef struct { double trough; double peak; } Edges;

class EdgeSensor  //mixin for BaseSensor
 {
   public:
      EdgeSensor (BaseSensorData * pBsd, size_t _windowSize,
                  const double _rangeFactor)
       { std::cout << "EdgeSensor: " << _windowSize << " "
            << pBsd->sensorName << " " << _rangeFactor << std::endl; }
 };

class CO2Threshold //mixin for ThresholdSensor
 {
   private:
      std::map<std::string, double> thresholds;

   public:
      CO2Threshold (const double & _toxicThres, const double & _zeroThres,
                    const double & )
       {
         thresholds["toxic"] = _toxicThres;
         thresholds["zero"] = _zeroThres;
         std::cout << "CO2Threshold: " << _toxicThres << " "
            << thresholds["zero"] << std::endl;
       }
};

class O2Threshold //mixin for ThresholdSensor
 {
   private:

      std::map<std::string , double> thresholds;

    public:

      O2Threshold (const double & _toxicThres, const double & _lowThres,
                   const double & _elecChemThres)
       {
         thresholds["toxic"] = _toxicThres;
         thresholds["low"] = _lowThres;
         thresholds["elecchem"] = _elecChemThres;
         std::cout << "O2Threshold: " << _toxicThres << " "
            << thresholds["low"] << " " << thresholds["elecchem"]
            << std::endl;
       }
 };

template <typename ThresholdMixin> //CO2Threshold , O2Threshold , or others ...
class ThresholdSensor : public ThresholdMixin  //mixin for BaseSensor
 {
   public:
      ThresholdSensor (BaseSensorData * pBsd, const size_t & _windowSize,
                       const double & _toxicThres)
         : ThresholdMixin
            ( _toxicThres, //3x the same arg
              _toxicThres, //just for the sake
              _toxicThres)  //of this exercise
       { std::cout << "ThresholdSensor: " << _windowSize << " "
         << pBsd->sensorName << " " << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public BaseSensorData, public SensorType ...
 {
   public:

      BaseSensor (const std::string & _sensorName, size_t _windowSize,
                  const double d)
         : BaseSensorData(_sensorName), SensorType(this, _windowSize, d )...
            { std::cout << "BaseSensor: " << _windowSize << " "
              << sensorName << " " << std::endl; } 
 };

int main()
 {
   BaseSensor<ThresholdSensor<CO2Threshold>,
      TrendSensor, EdgeSensor> bs { std::string("test"), 60U, 14.5f };

   //BaseSensor<EdgeSensor> bs2;
 }
```

Comment: what is it you do not like particularly about this solution?

Comment: @nass - It's question of personal taste, I suppose, but... I prefer use references to object instead of pointers to object, when possible